# node-gyp serialport build error on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: node.js, electron, raspberry-pi4, node-gyp, node-serialport

I have a nodejs electron app running on a Raspberry Pi 4.  The latest raspberry pi OS will not build the application (and older OS versions will not run on the latest hardware.)  I fairly sure this centers on the `serialport` package.  I have tried building a bare-bones electron app with just the `serialport` package and it does not work either.  Is this a system configuration issue or package version(s)?  I have tried Node 12, 14, & 16; serialport 9 & 10...?

I get the following error when doing `npm i`:

```
> usb@2.5.0 install /home/myapp/myapp/node_modules/usb
> node-gyp-build

> lzma-native@8.0.6 install /home/myapp/myapp/node_modules/lzma-native
> node-gyp-build

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.56-v7l+
gyp ERR! command "/home/myapp/.config/nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/node" "/home/myapp/myapp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/myapp/myapp/node_modules/lzma-native
gyp ERR! node -v v12.22.12
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN myapp-app@1.3.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: appdmg@0.4.5 (node_modules/appdmg):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for appdmg@0.4.5: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! lzma-native@8.0.6 install: `node-gyp-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the lzma-native@8.0.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/myapp/.npm/_logs/2022-08-26T13_57_08_118Z-debug.log
```

The error message is some string interpolation in a python script printing version info...

Comment: It looks like that package requires Python 2 to be installed (and available as `python`) to be built correctly.

Comment: Concur with @AKX. The reason is that you're using very old versions of Node.js and `node-gyp`.

Comment: As I said: I've tried it with the latest versions~ same result.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigating (using Node@16 & serialport@10), springing from this line:

`node-gyp -v v3.8.0`

I installed node-gyp locally:

`npm i node-gyp@latest -D`

...and that clears this install error.  Other packages depend on older versions of `node-gyp` which is causing runtime problems but this particular issue is cleared...

Comment: Thank you.  That does help wth this issue.  The electron app still doesn't run but that's another rabbit trail...